# Use Direct Comparison test to show Divergence

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

4.Use Direct Comparison test to show that :

$$\int_1^\infty\cfrac{1+e^{-x}}{x}dx      \qquad \qquad (a)$$ Diverges

Is equal to :

\begin{align}
& =\int_1^\infty \cfrac{1+\cfrac{1}{e^x}}{x}dx \\
& = \int_1^\infty \cfrac{\cfrac{e^x+1}{e^x}}{x}dx\\
& = \int_1^\infty \cfrac{e^x+1}{xe^x}dx\\
\end{align}

I also done $xe^x\geqslant e^x+1$

In this step i've thinked of doing a substitution, but drives me nowhere, for what function is convenient to compare ?

Comment: Note that $1+e^{-x}>1$, then your integrand is greater than $1/x$, and the last one diverges.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:
$$\frac{1+e^{-x}}{x}\ge\frac1x\quad\forall x\ge1$$

Answer (score 2):

You can use the limit comparison, comparing with 
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{x}.
\end{equation*}